# Compare two rows from different files in Python and write the matches to a output file

Tags: python

I have two CSV files. Both of these files contain different information. I am trying to compare one column from the first csv file to the other column in the second CSV file in python and save the matches to a third CSV file.

File 1 contains multiple columns with few records. File 2 contains 10 columns with a lot of records.

For example, please find the attached screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdAAs.png)

```py
import csv
import csv  
import sys
import codecs
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import io
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


with open('Output.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f2:
    with open('Input1.txt', 'r') as t1, open('Input2.txt', 'r') as t2:
        reader = csv.reader(t1, delimiter = ',')
        reader1 = csv.reader(t2, delimiter = ',')
        f2.write('Case_Number:'+'Comment 1:'+'Comment 2'+'\n')
        firstline = True
        for row in reader:
            for row1 in reader1:
                if firstline:
                    firstline = False
                    continue

                if row1[0].lower() in row[6].lower():
                    f2.write(row[0]+':'+'SBN NOtification'+':'+row1[1]+'\n')
f2.close()
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you're having with your code, including a description of the actual output compared to the expected output, or a full traceback of any exception you're getting.

Comment: Posting a spec and a code snippet doesn't make a question. Please read this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then come back and edit your post.

Comment: Please find attached screenshot. I would like the output combination of the two Csv files.